# Is calling flush onFileOutputStream enough?

Tags: java, flush, fileoutputstream

So of course we must try-catch-finaly any Closable resource.

But I came across some code which sins as follows:

```
java.util.Properties myProps = ... reads & loads (and doesn't close Stream!) 
myProperties.store(new FileOutputStream(myFilePath), null);
System.exit(0);
```

`java.util.Properties.store()` flushes the underlying stream (the `FileOutputStream`)
Will this be enough?
Can you think of a scenario where the file won't be written? assuming that the method passes and no exception is being thrown in 'store'

Answer (score 1):

It is enough in this specific case, but it is nevertheless very bad practice. The `FileOutputStream` should be *closed,* not merely flushed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want open file references I would close the streams. Flushing only makes sure that all changes are written to file.

Comment: There can't be any open file references after `System.exit()`.